# Fetch comma separated values in correspondent checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, fetch

I am working on a property web site. They want to enter all specifications of the house or apartment. I want to fetch data from  1 database field.

Please check Example picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XBEI.jpg

If value is like See in Cafe,YP Online then both See in Cafe & YP Online check boxes must be checked.
This is only a Example Form, i have more than 100 checkboxes. I do not want to make 100 fileds only for checkboxes.

looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Do you have more than 100 checkboxes for any single topic? Also, as written, this question is too broad for SO, and it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on a property web site. They want to enter all properties of any property. I want to fetch data from database field. If value is like See in Cafe,YP Online then both See in Cafe & YP Online check boxes must be checked. example http://i.stack.imgur.com/7XBEI.jpg

Comment: Amend your question accordingly.

Comment: i have already Amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to right database entry based on the checkboxes selected, or automatically highlight the checkboxes that are in the database as well?

```
<?php
    /*
    *   Assuming MySQLi initialized as $mysqli
    *   Assuming <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    */

    $found = array();

    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
        if(!$s = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `table` WHERE `value` LIKE '%$checkbox%'")) {
            // No result
        } else {
            $result = $s->fetch_assoc();
            $found[$result['id']] = $result['value'];
        }
    }
?>
```